# Having problems running system commands from a java program:

Tags: java

This is giving just the output of `ls`:

```
String[] cmd={"bash","-c","ls","-l"}:  
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
```

Whereas this is giving long listing output properly:

```
String[] cmd={"bash","-c","ls -l"};
```

Comment: Running on Windows XP. If that matters.
Thanks

Comment: I want to know why is it not giving the output for the first way i have mentioned.The output should be a long listing.

Comment: The first example, you are using bash to parse the command line. Try `{ "ls", "-l" }`

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. But what if I want to dynamically display files using cat command. An example scenario would be when I want to pass file names in a loop for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code snippet, the `-l` option is being passed as an argument to bash, and not to ls. Bash interprets the `-l` option as specifying that it should behave as a 'login' shell.

The argument after `-c` should include the whole bash script (spaces included) that you want to be executed, so the second code snippet is correct.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. But what if I want to dynamically display files using cat command. An example scenario would be when I want to pass file names in a loop for display.

Comment: If you want to invoke `cat` once with multiple parameters, then you could use a StringBuilder and `for` loop to build up the command line into a single string (with spaces between file names). That could be appended onto the string `"cat "`, and used for the command line argument following `-c`.

Answer (score 0):

The former passes two option flags to `bash`: `-c` with argument `ls`, and `-l` which according to the manpage causes `bash` to act as a login shell.

The second passes one option flag, `-c`, which the argument `ls -l` as a single string.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. But what if I want to dynamically display files using cat command. An example scenario would be when I want to pass file names in a loop for display

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] cmd={"bash","-c","ls -l"}:  
ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
```

The arguements are to bash, so if you want bash to interpert your "command" via "bash", "-c", ...
then the next item needs to be your entire command, aka "ls -l".

Bash will then parse up the "command" and the -l will be sent as a parameter to "ls".  Currently it is a parameter to "bash", which is why you're not getting the results you desire.